# ROW_NUMBER & PARTITION

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to use `ROW_NUMBER OVER PARTITION` to blank out certain values unless someone can suggest a better way, my data looks something like this

```
create table Emp_Details
(  Emp_Name varchar(10)
, Company varchar(15)
,Qty int
,LineOrderCost money
,OrderUnitCost money
,ExtraCost money
,ExtraDesc varchar(5)
) 

insert into Emp_Details (Emp_Name, Company, Qty, LineOrderCost, OrderUnitCost, ExtraCost, ExtraDesc)
values 
('John', 'PStock', 1, '2.50','3.50', '7.50', 'ABC')
,('John', 'PStock', 1, '2.50','3.50', '7.50', 'DEF')
```

What I want to do is return both records but set the `LineOrderCost`, `OrderUnitCost`, `ExtraCost` to 0 on the second line or if there are more than just 2 lines all following lines after the first one, hence when `Emp_Name`, `Company` and `Qty` are the same but the ExtraDesc is different blank out those values as described.

I apologies if I have not described this to well but in my head it makes some sort of sense :-)

Thanks P

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER` could be used to help achieve this, but why don't you do presentation in the presentation layer?

Comment: Can you add the expected output of the select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Select EMP_NAME,COMPANY,QTY, EXTRADESC,
    Case when row>1 then 0 else ORDERUNITCOST end as ORDERUNITCOST,
    Case when row>1 then 0 else LINEORDERCOST end as LINEORDERCOST,
    Case when row>1 then 0 else EXTRACOST end as EXTRACOST
    from
    (Select Row_Number() Over(Partition By EMP_NAME order by EMP_NAME) as row,* from 
    Emp_Details) t
```

[***Sql Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f20a8/1)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the responses and as AmitSingh posted I managed to get it working but its good to see I was going in the right direction.  I could of added it to the presentation layer by my SSRS is not amazing and as it was a one of I thought this would be the best way to go.  Thanks for all the help though!